# UIActionsheet with UIpagecontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2MHp.png">

I want to create actionsheet view like this image i post.Please suggest me how to we create this view using UIActionsheet.Is it posible to add views in uiactionsheet or how it is posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this control, it should satisfy your needs:
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aaactivityaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIActivityViewController` to achieve the design you have attached.

You can find the similar UI it in apple developer documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW121